# Firebase Functions - Function not being called

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have created the following functions:

It has been deployed and is there on the firebase hosting, but it just doesn't ever get called (usage is 0)...

It should be called when a user document is changed and then update a field to null if it wasn't already null.

Can anyone see why this is not running?

```
exports.deleteField = functions.database.ref('/Users/{userID}')
  .onUpdate((change, context) => {
    const overrideTag = change.after.data().overrideTag
    if (overrideTag !== null) {
      const db = admin.firestore()
      db.collection('Users').doc(userID).set({ overrideTag: null })
    }
  })
```

Kind Regards,
Josh

Comment: Please edit the question to be **very specific** about what you're doing that should trigger this function.  It's not possible to see just from the code why it's not being triggered.

Comment: As I have said above, the function should be trigger when a document in Users is changed.

Comment: In the absence of specific information, I can only take a guess.  Ideally, your question includes the specific steps you take to modify the document, perhaps also showing a screenshot of what it is you're working with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is configured to trigger on changes to a node called "Users" in Realtime Database.  Realtime Database doesn't have "documents".  However, Firestore does have documents.  If you meant to trigger when a document is changed in Firestore, you will have to write a [Firestore trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) instead.  It will use `functions.firestore` instead of `functions.database`.

Comment: Thank you for your response, clearly was enough detail as this gave me the answer.

Comment: So, we still needed to know that you were adding the document to the correct collection - that is also a common mistake.  It's never a bad idea to be very specific.  Screenshots help.